# Wordpress shortcodes bug in custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a theme from scratch and I have issues creating shortcodes. I have the following code:

functions.php

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<span class="caption">' . $content . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'caption', 'caption_shortcode' );
```

in the WP Admin page editor:

```
 [caption]My Caption[/caption]
```

on the page template page:

```
echo do_shortcode('[caption]');
```

The shortcode seems to be somehow working as it returns the HTML  but not the $content.

My problem is that I can't seem to get my hand on the $content and display it using the shortcode. Any idea why this is happening?

P.S. I don't want to use the_content() function to display all the content, I want to use the shortcodes to divide the content the user adds in several pop-ups and child sections of the page.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `echo do_shortcode('[caption]My Caption[/caption]');`?

Comment: It works, but I don't want to add the content from the code, I want the user to be able to add and delete it anytime.

Comment: you either can add the content via editor or the comment provided above . Else you can create a textbox ACF for every content and then write <?php echo do_shortcode('[caption]'.get_field("field_name").'[/caption]');?>

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you user shotcode same page

```
  // [baztag]content[/baztag]
    function baztag_func( $atts, $content = '' ) {
        return $content;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'baztag', 'baztag_func' );

 echo do_shortcode('[baztag]');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.